# How to convince upcoming employees that it's fair to have a Saturday as working day?

Tags: software-industry, company-culture, india, company-policy, work-time

In India, since childhood we have seen our parents, grandparents working 6 days a week and take off on Sundays. When I started my journey with IT companies into the corporate world, I was awarded *"Saturdays off"*.

Later started my own small company and continued this culture for 5 years. Slowly I realize that there are many downsides of Saturdays off. So I converted 8 hr x 5 days job into 6:40 hr x 6 days, keeping the working hours same. Employees got slowly adjusted to this new way of life. Though they had questions on 'Why this change'? Below were my reasons:

- Saturdays morning could be wasted in non productive or unwanted leisure. As a company we intend to encash those mornings.
- Employees start getting the feeling of weekend by Friday itself. If "Saturdays" are working then this feeling will subside greatly on Fridays.
- Hangover issue on Mondays due to 2 consecutive holidays between weeks. This mitigates if "Saturdays" are working.
- All hours of the days are not the same. Generally the post-lunch hours are for power nap (mild resting) & evenings are for recreational activities. We start our office from early morning hours like 7-8 am. Productivity wise 8 hr x 5 days is not same as 6:40 hr x 6 days. Latter is better!

Overall I feel that this strategy has worked out good for mental health as one needs not spend several hours in front of computers in a stretch.

**Queries**:

- How to convince upcoming employees that Saturday working is good for them?
- Has there **any research** happened in this area in western or other countries, which **supports this concept** and I can present as a ready reference?

---

**Update**:

- I don't see any quality issue, yet the question is downvoted as if it's a "meta" question for some suggestion. Possibly many people may have felt offended, which is not intended here. This is meant for a healthy discussion.
- Whatever reasons I have mentioned are my own perceptions, which I have derived from my experience on work-life balance as well as from other social observation specific to India. I was also an employee for 8 years of my career and I never had any issues working full 6 days, though my companies didn't ask me to do so.
- I feel the answers until now are from "employee" perspective which are highly in opposition of this view. If any "employer" would like to answer here, then it will add another perspective to this post.

***"Saturday morning wasted"* controversy**

Many people find above point outrageous, may be due to lack of elaboration on my part, which is as following:

==> It must be clear that we don't ask extra weekly hours. Just that we want to place our majority working hours during their mornings, which are [considered more productive](https://www.inc.com/laura-garnett/the-scientific-reason-why-being-a-morning-person-will-make-you-more-successful.html#:%7E:text=A%20structured%20morning%20routine%20cultivates,especially%20in%20the%20business%20world.) from lot many studies compared to afternoons, evenings & nights.

I request the commenters & answerers to stop debating with each other on this point. Also don't form your response around personal opinion such as *"I won't work on Saturdays"*, this can be a part of it not the heart of it.

Comment: "Saturdays morning are wasted in non productive or unwanted leisure" - citation needed.

Comment: *"This question applies to all the companies across the world in general."* That is actually incorrect. Laws in each country are different. In may countries, it would be a big problem if a company would decide to do what you did in your company. Even more, there is a serious discussion in many countries to implement the 4 day x 8 hr workweek. I edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @LaconicDroid: contrary to the statement in the question, the entire context is "India" and the local laws and the local culture.

Comment: I'm sorry, but we can not answer questions about fairness, because fairness is subjective.

Comment: As stated, everything is subjective here, but I don't find your reasons convincing at all. They are just a mix of unsubstantiated claims (points 1 and 2), subjective beliefs (point 4) and paternalism (point 3).

Comment: My own personal beliefs aside, whether or not it's fair would be up to your employees. If you want to make them happiest, give them a choice between the two schedules.

Comment: If someone chooses to 'waste' Saturdays in non-productive or unwanted leisure, surely that's their decision, not yours.

Comment: @LaconicDroid more citations needed for the the miracles in point 3

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, I thought you'd said on some previous occasion that you've been accustomed to working very long hours? I mean 60 or 70 hours in 5 days, sounds worse to me than about 40 hours over 6 days.

Comment: *I don't see any quality issue...* One of the reasons for downvoting given in the tooltip is "not useful". I don't see the point of this question given that you've already changed the schedule and, according to you, the employees have adjusted. What problem are you trying to solve if you've already successfully changed the schedule? It's one thing for a question not to be generally useful but I can't figure out how this is useful to *you*.

Comment: @BSMP, (1) Though I have changed, I want to know the perspective of outside world if it's "fair". (2) Those who have already worked in 5 day schedule, may not want to adopt for 6 days. What kind of reasoning can be provided to them, if this approach is fair. And that's the main question. Just 3-4 hours and there are already 5 answers with lot of upvotes, comments & views. The discussion is certainly useful.

Comment: Wait, when you say, "to the new employees", do you actually mean *potential* new hires who are questioning this during interviews or do you mean you have people currently working for you who are refusing to do 6 days? Can you edit your question to clarify who you're trying to make your argument to?

Comment: Also, along the same lines of what BSMP is asking. By "new employees", do you mean you and existing managers won't be affected by this schedule change? Also, have you considered turning Wednesday into a day off and just trading that day with a Saturday?

Comment: "Saturdays morning are wasted in non productive or unwanted leisure. As a company we want to encash those mornings."  - in other words you think you OWN people.

Answer (score 22):

There's different cultural-norms at play here of course but if my current employer tried to change my working hours to spread them out over 6 days like you had done I'd be out the door so fast you wouldn't see which way I'd gone. And I wouldn't join one that offered a 6 pattern either - I'd *maybe* consider doing so for a short period of time if the money was absurdly good.

Having just one free day a week is a depressing way to live IMHO. Reduced time with your families and you can't do *anything* that takes more than the Sunday without taking time off work. No weekend trips away, no big DIY projects at home. Ugh.

> Is there any research happened in this area in western or other countries, which support this concept and I can present as a ready reference?

There is research going on in other countries with regards the length of the working week - but not in the direction your thinking of. Other countries are looking at the possibilities of a 4 day week instead, and generally that seems to be beneficial. There was a trial recently in the [UK](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-62966302) and the vast majority of the businesses involved said they were going to keep the 4-day pattern. Microsoft Japan [tried a 4-day week](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2019/nov/04/microsoft-japan-four-day-work-week-productivity) and saw a 40% **increase** in productivity!

Just want to take a moment to address a recent addition to the question:

> I feel the answers until now are from "employee" perspective which are highly in opposition of this view. If any "employer" would like to answer here, then it will add another perspective to this post.

As I think the links about the trials of 4-day weeks show **employers** are seeing benefits to reduced length work-weeks, not just employees.

I understand that the 6-day pattern is more common in India then elsewhere in the world, but that doesn't mean it's *good*, and the early indicators from basically every trial I've seen - some in very different cultures, has been that less days not more has been giving benefits to both employees and their employers.

The fact that your company's workpattern is 40hrs over 6 days rather than the more "traditional" 48hrs over 6 days probably makes your company *less* unpleasant than some of your competition, which presumably helps with retaining your staff even though I suspect they weren't happy about the change you made. But don't allow yourself to fall into the trap of assuming that they *like* the deal your offering -  when alternative employers start offering them a workpattern they actually prefer? You should probably expect an exodus.

And as someone who has both had teams working under them and been a business owner with employees of my own, my experience supports the notion that the productivity of employees who don't get sufficient proper breaks at the weekends suffers over time.

Comment: There is no limit to reducing working days. I have cousins in US, who work just 3 days a week with long working hours. But such behaviour may not look natural from 4-5 day workers. Similarly 6 day workers may not find 5 days workers natural, as one looses the evenings for recreational activities. Move further east like China/S.Korea/Japan, the working pattern becomes even more severe, where they work 10+ hr for 6 days. Wanted to see if a balance can be struck. BTW, one reason we often get to hear from the western clients is that: the people in their countries want to work less and demand more.

Comment: Taken to it's ultimate extreme most employee's would like to work 0 days, and the flipside is that employers would like every possible productive day/hour. **Neither is realistic** so finding an optimal balance point is key. The current research into the subject seems to be finding that going from 5 -> 4 days is providing good results for both sides - **not** going from 5 -> 6 days as you're doing. You asked for research from other countries hoping to support your position, turns out it does the opposite - research is about finding the answer, not the answer you *want*.

Comment: Yes, I did expect for any research happening for 6 day/wk scheduling with limited hours. But if it tuns out the other way around, I would like to see that too. For the sake of completeness, can you put links / references of those researches in your answer?

Comment: A 6 "shorter day" week isn't something I've managed to find anything on others trying I'm afraid. As for links - there are already links to the examples in the post. Microsoft Japan did provide a more in-depth analysis of their trial and it's results [here](https://news.microsoft.com/ja-jp/2019/10/31/191031-published-the-results-of-measuring-the-effectiveness-of-our-work-life-choice-challenge-summer-2019/) but it's in Japanese which may be a barrier.

Answer (score 8):

> Is it fair to ask Saturdays working with above criteria to the new employees?

No, since none of your criteria is based on any measurable piece of information.

> Is there any research happened in this area in western or other countries, which support this concept and I can present as a ready reference?

You are doing things backwards.  You need to have the research that clearly demonstrates the benefits of working Saturdays *before* you implement this schedule.  At this point, you are making your employees work on Saturdays based on nothing more than your personal opinion and are looking for ways to justify this opinion.  This is a bad business practice regardless of location/culture.

Comment: Honestly, I don't care if there's evidence that shows working 6 days is good for my employer and they can "encash" my time.

Comment: @PhilipKendall  Presumably the evidence would need to show benefits for the employee, otherwise it is worthless.

Comment: My feeling is that's not the OP's primary concern.

Answer (score 7):

Six working days is fair if it's the norm in your locale.

In my locale 6 day weeks are standard in the private sector, so no one would complain and there's no need for rationalisation.

In your particular case the rationalisations are that controlling your staffs leisure activities is best for their mental health. Personally as a father I would disagree, 2 days off means I can take my family somewhere overnight or two nights on a weekend and many other family activities are more easily accomplished.

Comment: Though I liked / upvoted your answer, it discusses an obvious thing *"if it's a norm in your locale..."*. That's true for anything you take, isn't it ?! Do you take vacation trip on every weekend? Just to accommodate something less-frequent, aren't you altering a mindset? It's like buying a BIG car for city ride, so that *sometimes* I can speed-up or travel farther. Such collective mindset actually affects socio-economic factors on a long run. BTW my kids were enrolled to 5 days/wk school. I happily moved them to a costlier 6 days/wk school. Not saying someone is right. Different mindsets. :-)

Answer (score 6):

I'm in the UK. If any employer suggested that here, you would be asked "are you completely bonkers?" Your concerns about my leisure would be answered with "what I do in my free time is none of your f***ing business". This seems rude, but any employer here trying this would be considered extremely rude and only getting what they deserve.

PS. Western countries are just very slowly beginning to move to four day weeks.

Comment: ... *and the jobs are moving to the eastern countries.*.

Comment: @iammilind - citation needed…

Answer (score 3):

In the Western world, the six-day week went out of fashion a century ago, although these were typically weeks of 50-odd or 60-odd hours overall.

It is however a novel case to have six days of 6.75 hours a day, adding up to about 40 hours a week.

If Indian society still has married women primarily as homemakers, and men still live fairly local to work (meaning 6 commutes are not too much more burdensome than 5), then the pattern may work overall. What men lose from the additional day of work (relative to the Western standard), they gain from the women being explicitly expected to cover all chores and child-rearing, which probably saves them work overall.

There is unlikely to be any specific research on the matter in the Western world. Obviously, shorter working days are considered more effective, but 6-day working is inconsistent with modern lifestyles. Research has predominantly focussed on reducing working days to four, and on releasing women from the home and into the labour market.

Also, economic research has shown that leisure days do increase economic consumption, which is a key way of stimulating demand. This lack of domestic demand may not be of great concern whilst India predominantly provides low-waged exports to the West, but it would be more important if India was looking to become more self-sufficient, or if the West started to cut back on imports from the developing world.

An absence of days off also, crucially, tends to disrupt the activities of professionals, who often use leisure time to enrich their knowledge and culture in ways that benefit the economy in the long-term.

And of course, whether it is "fair" is a very complicated question.